# How to pull a message from queue with time interval?

Tags: ros, queue, message

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I subscribe my node, I set messages queue size and callback function:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    ros::init(argc, argv, "scs_drive");

    ros::NodeHandle n;

    ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("scs", 1000, writePosCallback);

    ros::spin();
    return 0;
}
```

The incoming messages are being processed as soon as previous callback function operations are finished.
But I want to process incoming messages from queue not ASAP but each millisecond.

So maybe it is possible to pull messages here:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    ros::init(argc, argv, "scs_drive");

    ros::NodeHandle n;

    ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("scs", 1000, writePosCallback);
    
    ros::Rate loop_rate(1000);
    
    while (ros::ok()) {
        
        //some code here that pulls message from queue and process incoming data
        
        ros::spinOnce();
        loop_rate.sleep();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Or I need to set pause in callback function and it is the one choice to process messages with a certain time interval?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/268948/how-to-pull-a-message-from-queue-with-time-interval?/) by [Sergey Kravchenko](https://answers.ros.org/users/27657/sergey-kravchenko/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2017-08-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't think this is supported directly (ie: with some special spinner or something), but you could create your own [CallbackQueue](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/roscpp/html/classros_1_1CallbackQueue.html) and then call [CallbackQueue::callOne(..)](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/roscpp/html/classros_1_1CallbackQueue.html#ac5e4758b2c425431e27f7aae748d5f25) at the appropriate time.

Note that this will mean that you're probably more likely to run into buffer overruns as `spinOnce()` actually calls [callAvailable()](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/roscpp/html/classros_1_1CallbackQueue.html#af09f0cad0f93bb20dd280e01332032c0) which processes all available callbacks ([here](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/a8c5f9e95e6823417b67ee0da2fa0a91acd97ef5/clients/roscpp/src/libros/init.cpp#L552-L555)), so more regularly empties your queue.

---

It might already exist, but if you want to abstract this nicely you could implement a new spinner that implements this behaviour. Then you could instantiate that in your code instead of having to maintain your own `CallbackQueue` instance.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-08-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1